# How do I write a SQL query for a shown azure cosmos db documents?

Tags: sql, azure-cosmosdb

I have following documents in azure cosmos db collection.

```
// Document 1
{
    "c": {
        "firstName": "Robert"
    }
    "elements" : [
        {
            "a": "x2",
            "b": {
                "name": "yadda2",
                "id": 1
            }
        }
    ]
}

// Document 2
{
    "c": {
        "firstName": "Steve"
    }
    "elements" : [
        {
            "a": "x5",
            "b": {
                "name": "yadda2",
                "id": 4
            }
        },
        {
            "a": "x3",
            "b": {
                "name": "yadda8",
                "id": 5
            }
        },
    ]
}

// Document 3
{
    "c": {
        "firstName": "Johnson"
    }
    "elements" : [
        {
            "a": "x4",
            "b": {
                "name": "yadda28",
                "id": 25
            }
        },
        {
            "a": "x5",
            "b": {
                "name": "yadda30",
                "id": 37
            }
        },
    ]
}
```

I need to write a query that returns all documents which have "b" object whose name is "yadda2" (i.e. /elements/*/b/name=yadda2). In other words, this query should return document 1 and 2 but NOT 3.

I tried following but it did not work:

SELECT * FROM x where ARRAY_CONTAINS(x.elements, {b: { name: "yadda2"}})

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just modify your sql to :

```
SELECT * FROM x where ARRAY_CONTAINS(x.elements, {b: { name: "yadda2"}},true)
```

Result:

[image]

Based on the official [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql-api-sql-query-reference#bk_array_contains) , the boolean expression could specify if the match is full or partial.

Hope it helps you.

Comment: I love how the documentation of the last boolean parameter is just "bool_expr - Is any boolean expression.". Not at all useful, but the examples do explain a bit what it does.